# How to parse multipart/x-mixed-replace messages with python

Tags: python, aiohttp

I would like to parse a ip camera stream, which consist on a `multipart/x-mixed-replace` messages. The thing I would like to archive, that I get each multipart (separated by the boundary keyword) as a response (may be as an iterator).

I have no clue, how I could achieve that with python.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry.
I know nothing about `multipart/x-mixed-replace`.
But you could read data from [responst.content](http://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/client_reference.html#aiohttp.ClientResponse.content) chunk by chunk and parse it by hands.